# Pandas use cell value as dict key to return dict value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my question relates to using the values in a dataframe column as keys in order to return their respective values and run a conditional.

I have a dataframe, df, containing a column "count" that has integers from 1 to 8 and a column "category" that has values either "A", "B", or "C"

I have a dictionary, dct, containing pairs A:2, B:4, C:6

This is my (incorrect) code:

```
result = df[df["count"] >= dct.get(df["category"])]
```

So I want to return a dataframe where the "count" value for a given row is equal to more than the value retrieved from a dictionary using the "category" letter in the same row.

So if there were count values of (1, 2, 6, 6) and category values of (A, B, C, A), the third and forth row would be return in the resultant dataframe.

How do I modify the above code to achieve this?

Comment: following your logic and datas, just the fourth row is the resultant...

Comment: You are correct. I have amended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way to go is to add your dictionary into a the existing dataframe and then apply a query on the new dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'count': [4, 5, 6], 'category': ['A', 'B', 'C']})
dct = {'A':5, 'B':4, 'C':-1}
df['min_count'] = df['category'].map(dct)
df = df.query('count>min_count')
```

Comment: So there's no way to make a small adjustment to my code to achieve this? If not, I may opt for the method you have provided - thanks for this.

Comment: I think you should go with my solution, approve it pls

Answer (score 0):

following your logic:

```
import pandas as pd

dct = {'A':2, 'B':4, 'C':6}
df = pd.DataFrame({'count':[1,2,5,6],
                   'category':['A','B','C','A']})

print('original dataframe')
print(df)

def process_row(x):
    return True if x['count'] >= dct[x['category']] else False

f = df.apply(lambda row: process_row(row), axis=1)
df = df[f]

print('final output')
print(df)
```

output:

```
original dataframe
   count category
0      1        A
1      2        B
2      5        C
3      6        A

final output
   count category
3      6        A
```

Answer (score 0):

A small modification to your code:

```
result = df[df['count'] >= df['category'].apply(lambda x: dct[x])]
```

You cannot directly use `dct.get(df['category'])` because `df['category']` returns a mutable Series which cannot be used as a dictionary key (Dictionary keys need to be immutable objects)
So, `apply` and `lambda` to the rescue! :)